# Measurable injection from $C[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, reference-request

Apparently such a map exists, where $C[0,1]$ is equipped with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra induced by the uniform norm and $[0,1]$ the usual Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

This seems very surprising---that an injection exists, much less measurable. Anyone know how this map is constructed?

Comment: There's certainly an injection because $C[0,1]$ and $[0,1]$ have the same cardinality.

Comment: A quick proof of @Math1000's statement comes by noticing that a continuous function is uniquely specified by its values on a dense subset, and $[0,1]$ has a countable dense subset. So the cardinality of $C[0,1]$ is at most that of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$, which is the same as the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$. The cardinality of $C[0,1]$ is also at least that of $\mathbb{R}$ because the set of functions $\{ x \mapsto cx : c \in \mathbb{R} \}$ is contained in $C[0,1]$.

Comment: So if you can find a "nice" map from $C[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$, maybe you can compose it with a "nice" map from $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ to get the result. The obvious choice for the first map seems to be $f \mapsto \{ f(q_n) \}_{n=1}^\infty$ for some enumeration $\{ q_n \}_{n=1}^\infty$ of $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$. Though unfortunately I'm not sure this is surjective...

Comment: I will not provide a construction, but give you some terms to search for which are connected to the existence of such a map. Both $[0,1]$ and $C([0,1])$ are so-called **Polish spaces** (with their standard topologies), i.e. there are metrics (the standard ones) which make them complete, seperable metric spaces. It is a theorem of **descriptive set theory** that any two Polish spaces of the same cardinality are Borel-isomorphic, i.e. there is even a bijective map $f:[0,1]\to C([0,1])$ so that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are Borel measurable. The construction in the proof is of course complicated.